# Interested in a garbage collection algorithm with a minimum of pauses, willing to sacrifice space

Tags: algorithm, garbage-collection

I'm interested in designing a scheme flavor for doing audio synthesis, but I'm quite concerned with doing proper garbage collection when catering to the low latencies required for audio. I was wondering if someone in the field might be able to point me towards a garbage collection algorithm that might be suitable for this sort of environment. I was looking at realtime garbage collection, which would seem to make sense, as I'd like to bound the amount of time that the garbage collector takes so I don't get pauses in the audio... though perhaps a collector that's just "fast enough" and distributes its work well would be good enough? I'm not at all worried about multithreading/multiprocessing, and I'm definitely not worried about wasting tons of space in search of these goals. I'm after predictable, simple, and fast.

Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure, the question covers no proper context, no practical stuff. It's quite difficult to answer, I didn't vote down though.

Comment: What sort of context is needed? I was honestly not even gonna give the use case. I'm saying that I need an algorithm that does blah, and these are the compromises I'm willing to make. That's a completely satisfiable problem. It's also completely practical given that I've given a cool use case!

Comment: There are a lot of garbage collection algorithms out there. What have you looked at? Is there anything existing that's at all similar to what you're looking for? Typically, we expect these kinds of questions to come with a, "This is what I've tried," or "I'm looking for something that's similar to X (existing implementation), but with these changes . . ."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a single-process setting on Unix-like OSes, I heard of an amusing approach. (It was experimentally implemented for [Nickle](http://nickle.org/), but I don't know if it got merged to master.)

It uses a simple mark-sweep collector, but here's the trick: When you want to run a mark phase, `fork()`. The child process runs the marker, and sends a list of objects to free over a pipe back to the parent, which can incrementally free them at leisure.

This works because the child is operating in a copy-on-write snapshot of the parent's memory state, maintained with reasonable efficiency by the operating system's memory manager with help from a hardware MMU. Once an object becomes unreachable, it won't become referenced again, so marking from an old snapshot always gives a conservative estimate of objects that can be freed.

---

edit: Best reference I can find for this work is the Summer of Code proposal for it: http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~juenglin/revamping.html

Comment: The only problem is that `fork` is probably unacceptably-slow for this application (audio).